# How to remove whitespace overlay from bottombarApp on KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want remove this blank space that overlays ImageList, I've checked the documentation but there isn't a way to fix this.
I want the BottomAppBar to directly overlay the image, is there a way I can do this even if it's a Hack.

[image]

here's a code that does the same thing. (please, remember the question: how to make MDBottomAppBar transparent). I'll appreciate any contribution.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Hello'

        ScrollView:
            MDLabel:
                text:
                    """next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, next, """

        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                type: 'bottom'
                mode: 'end'
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        sm = Builder.load_string(KV)

        return sm


Example().run()
```

Comment: Consider providing a minimal working code

Comment: @watney I think the code isn't the issue.. I think it comes with kivymd. but there must be a way to fix this. I have been trying to to fix this, even in simple codes I put together it still has the same issues.. I have added a simple code that does this same thing. Thank you for you interest..